# how to prevent JsonConvert.SerializeObject from adding quotes around strings

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a section on my server that looks like this:

```
private static dynamic Data;
string ArraySize = "[900,900,2]";
Data = new { c2array = true, size = ArraySize };
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("json.txt", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data));
```

which spits this out:

{"c2array":true,"size":"[900,900,2]"}

yet in JavaScript I can get it to this with json.stringify:

{"c2array":true,"size":[900,900,2]} <--- no quotes

how can i get the c# JSON serialize to *not* wrap quotes around the string.

I'm using a string value because if I try the following

```
Data = new { c2array = true, size = [900,900,2] };
```

it won't compile

the client script I'm sending this to is a game programming library in JavaScript and it expects the size without quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make `ArraySize` a string.

```
var ArraySize = new int[] {900,900,2};
Data = new { c2array = true, size = ArraySize };
```

Comment: thankyou worked like a charm says I can't accept an answer for 7 minutes but will when it lets me